# SkyDrive file metadata

Tags: file, api, metadata, windows-8, onedrive

What kind of metadata is available per file in the skydrive api?

It would be great if it was possible to get a files checksum and last written time remotely before downloading the file. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the file checksum but you can get last modified time before downloading the file. Please refer to SkyDrive API for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#reading_files_props

Comment: as per your link the method is checking using its file id, but if there are lot of newly added files the device won't be having all those files and their file ids then how to show a notification to the user that how many files are new,     and moreover checking each and every file will take a long time is there anything to get the list of new files